# Lambda or a Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

In C#, When I write a lambda having a lambda parameter, I seem to get an error.  However when I use a function as opposed to the inner lambda all is well.

Is it my mistake?

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Compiles fine
        Func<Func<int>, double> ff1 = funcf2 => 5.0;

        // Generates a compilation error:
        // Error: 'Func<Func<int>, double>' does not take 0 arguments
        Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = (() => 1) => 5.0;
    }

    public static int funcf2() => 1;
}
```

Comment: My first thought is, why would you want to do this? It's not particularly readable and I can't think of a good use case for this?

Comment: You probably think `ff1` uses your static `funcf2()` function **it doensn't**. Delete the static method and `ff1` will still be valid.

Comment: @Liam: Well, use cases for this pattern are not hard to find. It may help to think of an equivalent function structure with named parameters (e.g. if it were a method on an interface): `Object CreateSomething(Func<int> generateId, double value)` - a factory function that uses one or more IDs supplied by the caller. It does, of course, only make sense if at least in some implementations, the `generateId` function might actually be invoked.

Comment: @Liam: The monad pattern is another use case

Comment: @GWigWam: you are correct.  Nevertheless, my question stands: why can I not write Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = (() => 1) => 5.0);

Comment: @AviFarah: How is `ff2` supposed to be used? It's still of type `Func<Func<int>, double>`, hence you'd still have to pass a `Func<int>` as an argument ... which would then invariably overwrite (?) the `() => 1` you are mentioning in the function?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you have a valid point and by now I believe that what I am asking for is impossible in C# the first parameter seems to need a symbolic name like "x" and cannot be a lambda expression like "() => 1".

Comment: @AviFarah: You say I have a valid point, yet you still haven't answered my question. I have no idea what you are trying to express (or what you expect the C# compiler to do) by indicating a lambda expression for a parameter instead of a symbolic name.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I was hoping to have C# pass the first parameter as the lambda "() => 1" so  
    Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = x => 5.0;
    ff2(() => 1); 

be done in a single step.  I saw no reason why this should not be done as such.  Though I understand that it is a syntactic limitation.

We cannot write an expression like: var x = () => 1 => 5.0;  So we have to explicitly specify what var is as such I felt that we should be able to express ourselves as: Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = (() => 1) => 5.0;

I hope that I am clear.

Comment: @AviFarah: I'm afraid not. It's still unclear to me what `var x = () => 1 => 5.0;` is supposed to express? What's the intended difference to `var x = () => 5.0;`? Or, if you require `x` to be of type `Func<Func<int>, double>`, what's the intended difference to `Func<Func<int>, double> x = funcf2 => 5.0;`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, `var x = () => 1 => 5.0;` is a syntactic mistake I meant `var x = (() => 1) => 5.0;` to me it **should** mean `Func<Func<int>, double>`.  I did not mean to say that this example is meaningful.  On the contrary I chose the simplest distilled example in order to make a point and `var x = (() => 1) => 5.0;` will yield the same result as `var x = () => 5.0;` but this is not a reason not to be able to express ourselves with `var x = (() => 1) => 5.0;`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I needed to split my response to 2.  Lastly, by `Func<Func<int>, double> x = funcf2 => 5;` I assume that you mean to populate the first parameter with the function that I proposed in my original question.  @GWigWam suggested that this will not work and I seem to concur with him.  So say, `Func<Func<int>, double> x = y => 5.0; x(funcf2)();`  There should be no difference.  I was hoping to be able to do it in a single step.

Comment: @AviFarah: So, you're trying to express `Func<Func<int>, double> x = y => 5.0; x(funcf2)();`in "a single step". But in that two-step example, the result of `x(funcf2)()` is of type `double`; you're *evaluating* the expression. In your question, you were still assuming the result of your single-step example `(() => 1) => 5.0` is of type `Func<Func<int>, double>`, i.e. the *definition* of the expression. Which one is it? You can very well *evaluate* such an expression in a single step in C#: `double x = ((Func<Func<int>, double>)(y => 5.0))(() => 1)` This will evaluate to the value 5.0.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was posted by O.R.Mapper:

Instead of writing `Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = (() => 1) => 5.0;` which does not compile.  We could write it as follows:

```
double x = ((Func<Func<int>, double>)(y => 5.0))(() => 1)
```

Thank you O.R.Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of a mistaken identity.

When you write this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Func<int>, double> ff1 = funcf2 => 5.0;
}

public static int funcf2() => 1;
```

You're assuming that the `funcf2` in the lambda refers to the `static int funcf2()`. It does not. It is a completely new variable.

Try writing it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Func<int>, double> ff1 = funcf2 => 5.0;
}

public static int funcf2_WOW_IT_HAS_A_NEW_NAME() => 1;
```

This still compiles and runs fine.

The issue is that we write `Func<Func<int>, double> ff1 = funcf2 => 5.0;` the `funcf2` is simply a variable that will represent the `Func<int>` in the future when you invoke the lambda.

Writing `Func<Func<int>, double> ff2 = (() => 1) => 5.0;` is just an illegal syntax. That's why it doesn't work.